# How to install org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Rpm for ant

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to launch:

```
ant rpm
```

command where my build.xml at line #126 looks like:

```
<rpm specFile="whatever.spec" topDir="${basedir}/rpm" command="-bb" failOnError="true" />
```

I'm getting the error:

```
build.xml:126: Problem: failed to create task or type rpm
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Rpm was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/export/home/myuser/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

I downloaded ant-nodeps-1.7.1.jar which contains:

```
jar tvf ant-nodeps-1.7.1.jar | grep Rpm
  7171 Fri Jun 27 05:03:48 CEST 2008 org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/Rpm.class
```

I placed this jar file to directory: /usr/share/ant/lib

```
ant-1.7.0.jar -> ../../java/ant-1.7.0.jar
ant.jar -> ../../java/ant.jar
ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar -> ../../java/ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar
ant-launcher.jar -> ../../java/ant-launcher.jar
ant-nodeps-1.7.1.jar
```

but still getting that build error.
I tried also with commands:

```
ant -lib /usr/share/ant/lib rpm
ant -lib /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-nodeps-1.7.1.jar rpm
ant -lib ant-nodeps-1.7.1.jar rpm
```

whithout succes, getting the same error.
What is missing, what I need to do ?

Thanks !

Comment: In the block starting with `ant-1.7.0.jar -> ../../java/ant-1.7.0.jar`, what do the `->` symbols represent? What is the output of `ant -version`?

Comment: That is actually the output of a '/bin/ls -l' command so the -> symbol represents the link of the symlink file. My ant version is 1.7.0. And the I downloaded a 1.7.1 ant-nodeps .. so yes, their version differs, but could that cause my error message ?

Answer (score 0):

cd into your ANT_HOME directory and run `ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=system`
This will download the optional ant dependencies you need to `ant rpm`.

This is from the [ant install guide](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html).